# Notification for downvoted posts when the post is updated?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, notifications

We are supposed to downvote a poor quality posts but most of the times the OP takes in the suggestions and edits their post.

Shouldn't the people who downvoted be notified when the post gets edited so they can come back and remove their downvote?